# How to resolve segmentation fault(core dumped) in laravel-5.8?

Tags: php, laravel-5.8

In my system i have two projects both are working fine but suddenly when i start my second project based on that url i hit the api in postman then it's showing like this

```
Laravel development server started: <http://127.0.0.1:8000>
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
Laravel development server started: <http://127.0.0.1:8001>
```

can you please help me how to resolve this issue

i tried the following commands

```
composer dump-autoload

php artisan clear-compiled

composer clear-cache
```

Comment: Did laravel start on 8001 port after crashing on 8000 ?

Comment: @Kandrat, again it's incrementing like this Laravel development server started: <http://127.0.0.1:8002>

Comment: did u try change port ?  something like
php artisan serve --port=9999

Comment: @Kandrat,i tried again getting same issue Laravel development server started: <http://127.0.0.1:9999>
Segmentation fault (core dumped)

Comment: https://jolicode.com/blog/find-segfaults-in-php-like-a-boss  check this one